# Best way to sharing function in react

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I'm new in react. I wonder what is the best option for sharing functions (except inheritance). In inheritance way I can do something like this:

```
class BaseForm {
    updateForm() => {};
}

class MyFormOne extends BaseForm {
    // this.updateForm();
}
```

And I can code few Form components which extends BaseForm and I can use updateForm method in every. What is the best way in react to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `utils.js` file and place your common JS functions there. Something like this:

```
export const updateFormCommon = (inputValue) => {

   // Your function logic here

   return something;
};

export const showMessage = () => {
   alert('hello world');
};
```

Now you can import `utils.js` wherever you need and call your common\shared functions like this:

```
import {updateFormCommon, showMessage} from './utils'

let result = updateFormCommon(1000)}

showMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for the question :

1) If the shared fnc is the static function (independent with the component). You should **create a common file utils.js** and then **export, import function** wherever you want

```
// utils.js
export function updateForm() { }

// MyformOne.js
import {updateForm} from './utils';
// Use fnc updateForm() in MyFormOne component
```

2) If the shared fnc is dependent with class component, you should use the design pattern in React : **HOC (Higher Order Component) or render Props** for sharing code (states, functions) between React components *(render your code more abstract => a good practice for reusable)*

```
class BaseForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a1 : "",
      a2 : "",
    }
  }

  // example : share the func updateForm of Baseform
  updateForm = () => {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/*
          use the `render` prop to dynamically determine what to render.
        */}
        {this.props.render(this.state, this.updateForm)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class WithBaseForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BaseForm render={(stateBaseForm, updateForm) => (
          <MyFormOne stateBaseForm={stateBaseForm} updateForm={updateForm}/> // so MyFormOne could use the fnc updateForm of BaseForm
        )}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You should view the link for more details :

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html